# Writable databases packed in an executable jar

Tags: java, derby, executable-jar

Is it possible to have a writable database packaged in an executable jar file that will be updated by that same jar?

If any relevant information can be given on Derby Embedded databases in particular that would be great, but I am open to switching database providers if it's possible at all.

Comment: I don't think it is possible and if it was, performances should be terrible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid it is not possible or require huge efforts.

I guess you're trying to make some "portable" application which will not require any additional steps to run it but still uses the database. If that is the case, I would suggest you to allow the user  specify where database files are located, for example using command line:

```
java -jar uber-jar.jar --db=/opt/database
```

Or just use `user.home` variable as a base path.

Then just pass the location within your jdbc connection string.